# How should I access attributes of union types in typscript?

Tags: typescript

What is the correct way to access attributes of a union type that is not present on all of the types? I seem to always get a typescript "property ... does not exist on type..." error, even if I do a check to make sure the attribute exists (see example below)

```
interface Car {
  wheels: 4,
  spareWheels: 1,
}

interface Bicycle {
  wheels: 2,
}

type Vehicle = Car | Bicycle


getWheelCount(vehicle: Vehicle): number => {
   return vehicle.spareWheels ? vehicle.spareWheels + vehicle.wheels : vehicle.wheels
}
```

The documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types ) has a solution to use 'typeof', but that doesn't work for custom types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [type-predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```js
interface Car {
  wheels: 4;
  spareWheels: 1;
}

interface Bicycle {
  wheels: 2;
}

type Vehicle = Car | Bicycle;

const getWheelCount = (vehicle: Vehicle): number => {
  return isVehiculeCar(vehicle) ? vehicle.spareWheels + vehicle.wheels : vehicle.wheels;
};

const isVehiculeCar = (subject: Vehicle): subject is Car => {
  return (subject as Car).spareWheels !== undefined;
};
```

This way Typescript will know when you are dealing with a `Car` or a `Bicycle`.

Technically, Typescript is inferring your `vehicule` var with `Car` type **after** the function `isVehiculeCar`. Meaning that if you are using an IDE with smart typing feature (like auto-completion) you will **only** have access to `Car` interface attributes in this scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` operator like this:

```
interface Car {
  wheels: 4;
  spareWheels: 1;
}

interface Bicycle {
  wheels: 2;
}

type Vehicle = Car | Bicycle;

const getWheelCount = (vehicle: Vehicle): number => {
  return "spareWheels" in vehicle // using `in` operator
    ? vehicle.spareWheels + vehicle.wheels
    : vehicle.wheels;
};
```